# How to IPC between node and python using posix message queue?

Tags: python, node.js, posix, ipc, mqueue

I'm trying to write a "hello world" of IPC between a node js and a python**3** application. At the moment I'm having a parse error when a new message arrives the Python app. The codes are:

Python:

```
from ipcqueue import posixmq
from time import sleep

q1 = posixmq.Queue('/fila1')

while True:

    while q1.qsize() > 0:
        print('p1: Recebi na minha fila: ' + str(q1.get()))

    sleep(0.5)
```

Node:

```
const PosixMQ = require('posix-mq')

var mq = new PosixMQ();
mq.open({
    name: '/fila1',
    create: true,
    mode: '0777',
    maxmsgs: 10,
    msgsize: 11
});
mq.push("hello world")
mq.close();
```

When the second app sends the message, the python app fails with:

> File "../test-fila1.py", line 9, in
>
> ```
> print('p1: Recebi na minha fila: ' + str(q1.get()))   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipcqueue/posixmq.py", line 174, in
> ```
>
> get
>
> ```
> return self._serializer.loads(data)   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipcqueue/serializers.py", line 14,
> ```
>
> in loads
>
> ```
> return pickle.loads(data) KeyError: 101
> ```
>
> [2]-  Exit 1                  python3 ../test-fila1.py
> [3]+  Done                    node index.js

**EDIT**
So, I decided to change the question from "KeyError: 101 when loading ipc message between node and python apps" to "How to IPC between node and python using posix message queue?" because I just noticed that the sample code I posted generates different errors everytime I run them. Now the error that is happening is (however, no code was changed):

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "snippets/test-fila1.py",
> line 9, in 
> print('p1: Recebi na minha fila: ' + str(q1.get()))   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipcqueue/posixmq.py", line 174, in
> get
> return self._serializer.loads(data)   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipcqueue/serializers.py", line 14,
> in loads
> return pickle.loads(data)
> _pickle.UnpicklingError: unpickling stack underflow

Comment: try sending an object from node.js rather than raw string e.g. mq.push({'data': 'hello world'});

Comment: the function doesn't accept it:
`TypeError: First argument must be a node::Buffer or v8::String`

Comment: try stringifying a JSON object message. e.g. message = {'data': 'hello world'}

mq.push(JSON.stringify(message))

Comment: yup, it also results in the same error that was happening:
`_pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '{'`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you look the `__init__` of the `Queue`

```py
class Queue(object):
    """
    POSIX message queue.
    """

    def __init__(self, name, maxsize=10, maxmsgsize=1024, serializer=PickleSerializer):
```

As you can see the default `serializer` is `PickleSerializer`, which means it assumes the data coming on the queue is pickled, while you are sending raw data from `nodejs`. The fix is simple, use the `RawSerializer`

```py
from ipcqueue import posixmq
from time import sleep
from ipcqueue.serializers import RawSerializer
q1 = posixmq.Queue('/fila1', serializer=RawSerializer)

while True:

    while q1.qsize() > 0:
        print('p1: Recebi na minha fila: ' + str(q1.get()))

    sleep(0.5)
```

[image: Working fine]